# What is the difference between 影 and 陰

Tags: meaning, kanji

Some people said that 影 is shadow while 陰 means shade and refers to a shadow or shade that sun or light can't reach. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, 影 is a 2-dimensional shape (with contour) created on a surface by an object blocking light (cast on the surface) and 陰 is  3-dimensional space between the object and the shadow where it is dark.

I think it is better to look at [examples](https://kotokurabe.com/shadow/) to get the idea. And of course, you need to consult dictionaries for figurative uses.

---

FYI ["Shade" vs. "shadow"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/shade-vs-shadow)